# How can I run AirDrop from the Dock?

Tags: macos, dock, airdrop

Heading says it all. I just want to run AirDrop from the Dock like any other app.

Possible or not? How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, there’s an AirDrop app you **can** add to the Dock.

Follow these steps:

1. Within Finder, press the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> keys
2. A **Go to Folder** window appears
3. Now copy and paste the file path below into the field

   `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Applications/`
4. Click on the <kbd>Go</kbd> button
5. Now you’ll see a list of apps, including AirDrop
6. Drag the AirDrop app to your Dock

Now you can access AirDrop from your Dock whenever you want like any other app.